# how to save visualization output of NVIDIA DIGITS to a folder?

Tags: nvidia-digits

I am using NVIDIA DIGITS for image classification. After I train my network and I test the model on the test data, I want to save the visualization and statistics that DIGITS can generate in my defined folder. How can I do it?

For example how can I save each image square of the following image separately in a folder I specify in the program written for this part??

[image]